# Previous Screen Path on Google Analytics for Mobile

Tags: android, ios, mobile, google-analytics

On Google Analytics for websites there is a dimension "Previous Page Path", that shows the page that the user was before entering on current page.
But I not finding a similar dimension for mobile version.
I want to know the previous screen that the user was before entering the current screen.

I'm not finding it, or does not really exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

equivalent of previous page path is not available in app analytics because calculating previous page is considerably easier on web with "http referer" in app there is nothing equivalent of that.

I have tried an alternate solution I tried to create a custom dimension called previous screen and tried to populate it with by storing screen names in local storage. But I ran in to trouble with max length of custom dimension which is 150 bytes. Best way to get this is i guess by using Google Big query.

Hope this helps

Regards
Nik

Comment: Thanks! Using a custom dimension is a good workaround to this